# don't understand how to use jQuery $.each to iterate this JSON

Tags: jquery, json, each

I get JSON from my server and I want to set values of input boxes on a web page. The JSON pairs are the id and value of the inputs. The test JSON looks like

```
[{"city":"Rochester, Monroe County","country":"US","streetAddress":"12 Gibbs Street"}]
```

The real JSON will be much longer with more key value pairs in the one object.

When I use this hard coded statement, it sets the input value.

```
$('#city').val( responseParsed[0].city );  //this sets the city input to a value
```

I have tried to extend/automate that with $.each. I'm trying to learn to use it. I just can't get the hang of it. I'm feeling dense, at the moment, after many attempts.  Here's the code for the success option in ajax.

```
success: function ( response ) {    
    if ( response ) {
        responseParsed = JSON.parse( response );
        $.each( responseParsed, function( key, value ){
            $('#key').val( responseParsed[0].key );
            console.log( $('#key').val( responseParsed[0].key ) + '|eachItem' ); // [object Object]|eachItem only once & input values do not change
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `responseParsed` inside your `$.each`.  That's what the `key` and `value` parameters mean.

Your `value` (or `this`) is the current element of the array.

```
$.each(responseParsed, function(key, value){
    $('#city').val(value.city);
});
```

To get each key from the object, you'd need another `$.each`:

```
$.each(responseParsed, function(index, data){
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $('#'+key).val(value);
        console.log(key, value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Rocket Hazmat, thanks, it works great.  Could you explain the function(index, data) and function(data, function(key, value). I understand the key, value, but is data the same content in both places, and if so, what is it? I read the rest of the code, but I don't get that "double data" part. Thank you, again.

Comment: @Mike_Laird: When you're looping over `responseParsed`, `index` is the key in the array, and `data` is the array's value.  That value is an object.  We need to loop over that object, so we call `$.each` on `data`, just like we did on `responseParsed`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
success: function ( response ) {    
    if ( response ) {
        responseParsed = JSON.parse( response );
        $.each( responseParsed[0], function( key, value ){
            $('#' + key).val(value);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work and it breaks the function the whole thing is nested in.

Comment: Sorry, i made only one loop , thats wrong. 
The code of Rocket is correct.